# How to detect rows with chinese characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, non-ascii-characters

How can I detect and delete rows with Chinese characters in MySQL?

Comment: What collation/character set is the table in?

Comment: Maybe, `NOT RLIKE '[[:ideogram:]]+'` would work, but not sure at all.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the **Table** "Chinese_Test" Contains the Chinese Character on my PhpMyAdmin
**Data:**

[image]

**Structure**
[image]

notice my type of Collation is utf8, thus let's take a look at the Chinese Characters in utf8 table. 
http://www.ansell-uebersetzungen.com/gbuni.html

Notice the Chinese Character is from E4 to E9, hence we use the code

```
select number 
from Chinese_Test
where HEX(contents) REGEXP '^(..)*(E[4-9])';
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: how to check for other languages ? where will I get the regexp for other language like hindi?

Answer (score 0):

If all the other rows have alphanumeric values try the following:

```
DELETE FROM  tableName WHERE NOT columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9.,-]';
```

Do check the results before deletion, using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE NOT columnToCheck REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9.,-]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but to provide you with a starting point: Chinese characters will occupy certain blocks in the UTF-8 character set. [Example](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/cjk_unified_ideographs/utf8test.htm)

You would have to query for rows that contain characters between the first and the last point of that block. I can't think of a way to automate this though (i.e. to query for characters inside a certain range without naming each character explicitly).

Another untested idea that comes to mind is using `iconv()` to convert the string to a specifically Chinese encoding, using `//IGNORE`, and seeing whether any data is left. If anything is left,  the string may contain chinese characters.... although this would probably be disrupted by any numbers inside the string,

It's an interesting problem.